# Как запустить компьютер, если операционная система не грузится?

Tags: пк

Включил компьютер, но возникла проблема: операционная система не запускается. При включении черный экран, иногда появляется сообщение о возможности нажать F2, F11 или Del. Нажал Del (или F2) и попал в настройки BIOS. Не знаю, что делать, но нужно запустить компьютер. Как решить проблему?

Срочно нужна помощь! Спасибо за поддержку!

Comment: Попробуйте включить нажимая (часто) клавишу F8, должно появится меню на черном фоне. Где будет пункт "Последняя удачная загрузка". Если вы в Биос входите и на экране что-то видите, значит видеокарта не сгорела ;) Предупреждение: иногда нажатие F8 не срабатывает, но пробуйте еще раз.

Comment: Нужно смотреть в BIOS виден ли вообще диск с операционкой хотя бы на аппаратном уровне.

Answer (score 1):

На моей практике чаще всего это происходит из-за неисправности блока питания. Возможно неисправно что-то другое . память, жесткий диск, материнская плата. Жесткий диск и процессор перед смертью очень тупят.